# Android onTouch Activity New XML File Error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, ontouchlistener

I have 3 XML files. The first one is for main activity. It has one button. When I touch this button, it works and it sends me to second XML file. Also the second screen has a button. Now, I want to make same operation here and I wanna go third XML file. But it doesn't work.

I did same procedure for all buttons. I can't find that where is my fault.

`MainPageActivity`:

```
public class MainPageActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);

    ImageButton b1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_compare);
    ImageButton b2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_find);
    b1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View comparePage, MotionEvent event) {
        setContentView(R.layout.compare_pagee);
        return true;
      }

    });

    b2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View findPage, MotionEvent event) {
        setContentView(R.layout.find_page);
        return true;
      }

    });

  }


  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_page, menu);
    return true;
  }
}
```

`activity_main_page.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainPageActivity"
android:id="@+id/mainActivity" >
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/button_compare"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="center"
android:src="@drawable/compare"
/>
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/button_find"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="69dp"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:src="@drawable/find" 
/>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:text="Tap the top to Compare!"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/button_compare"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:text="Tap the bottom to Find!"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

`Compare`:

```
public class Compare extends Activity{

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.compare_pagee);


    ImageButton b3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.compareButton);
    b3.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View comparePage, MotionEvent event) {
        setContentView(R.layout.compare_pagee);
        return true;
      }

    });

  }
}
```

`compare_pagee.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundwallpaper"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Compare" >
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1" />
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1" />
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner5"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1" />
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/compareButton"
android:layout_width="139dp"
android:layout_height="74dp"
android:src="@drawable/comparebutton" />
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner6"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1" />
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner4"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1" />
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'd love to mind read but I can't. Post your code and your xml files so we can see what's happening.

Comment: I have added my codes. When I touch the **b3 button**, I want to go an other XML (layout screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not starting new Activities, you're merely switching layouts in the first Activity. So the first button will work because it has a listener assigned to it in MainActivity. However `b3` is is another Activity which never gets started, so depending on what you want to do, you can either start a new Activity for each button click, or you can move `b3`'s Listener inside `MainActivity`.

First method (new Activities)

```
ImageButton b1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_compare);
ImageButton b2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_find);
b1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View comparePage, MotionEvent event) {
    startIntent (new Intent (MainPageActivity.this, Compare.class));
    return true;
  }

});

b2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View findPage, MotionEvent event) {
    startIntent (new Intent (MainPageActivity.this, Find.class));//You will NEED to make a new Activity called Find.
    return true;
  }

});
```

The second way (resetting content views in the same activity). I do not recommend it, since it makes things messy and goes against what an Activity should be, but it's still a (bad) option.

```
ImageButton b1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_compare);
ImageButton b2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_find);
b1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View comparePage, MotionEvent event) {
    setContentView(R.layout.compare_pagee);
    ImageButton b3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.compareButton);
    b3.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View comparePage, MotionEvent event) {
        setContentView(R.layout.compare_pagee);
        return true;
      }

    });
    return true;
  }

});

b2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View findPage, MotionEvent event) {
    setContentView(R.layout.find_page);
    return true;
  }

});

}
```

As you can see, b3's Listener extremely redundant - it doesn't do anything useful.

I suggest rethinking what you want your code to do, and rewriting it properly, since this is not proper structure.

Comment: for example, when i tap the b3 button, i want to show some search results in the another xml page. i'am tapping the b1, i can pass the second xml page. but when i tap the b3 button in the second xml file, i couldnt pass the third xml page. i am not sure which way is easier or more efficient to make this and already i couldn't make the code work neither with intents nor onTouchListeners.

Comment: `b3` sets the content view to the exact same xml that was current (`compare_pagee`). Maybe you need to change the onTouch for `b3` to point to an xml other than `compare_pagee`?

Comment: onCreate i'm doing setContentView(R.layout.compare_pagee); and onTouch im doing  setContentView(R.layout.compare_page2); am i wrong?

Comment: The code in your question says otherwise, so I think you should update it. Anyways you're very unclear about this, is the `Compare` Activity actually starting or are you merely fiddling with the content views in `MainActivity`?